# how can i make list dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

i'm in a trouble to make a list for plot my data

lists for plot

X : age

Y : counted values per age

Ex.)

```
x = [0, 1, 2, ... ]

y = [[counted_female_age0, counted_female_age1, ...], [counted_male_age0, counted_male_age1, ...]]
```

so, I did

```
# get x
ages = sorted(user_data['age'].unique().tolist())

# get y
for i in ages:
    category = user_data['sex'].unique().tolist()
    for cat in category:
        user_data[(user_data['age'] == i) & (user_data['sex'] == 'cat')]['sex'].count()
```

```
# sample data
data = {'age':[21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 20, 21, 19, 20, 19, 21, 20, 19, 19, 20, 21, 21],
        'sex':['F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M']}
user_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['age','sex'])
```

i can count the values but i don't know make nested list dynamically

how can i make it?

Comment: i added some data.

Comment: no i just want to know how to make nested list dynamically, but quite helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? a **list of list with [[female counts], [male counts]]**

1. sorting data:

[image]

2. Then group by for count and convert to list:

[image]

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'age':[21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 20, 21, 19, 20, 19, 21, 20, 19, 19, 20, 21, 21],
        'sex':['F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M']}
user_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['age','sex'])

# sorting values
user_data = user_data.sort_values('age')
print('sorted DF:')
print(user_data)

# group by for count
group_df  = user_data.groupby(['age','sex'])['sex'].count().reset_index(name="count")
print('group by :')
print(group_df)

print('result:')
print(group_df.groupby('sex')['count'].apply(list).values.tolist())
```

Comment: thank you! the result is just what i want.
i still want to know some logical technic to achieve this, but now i know groupby function can solve it

Comment: Just go through aggregation function in pandas once and you will be good to go. @Kyon You can accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab), then turn the `columns` and `values` `tolist`:

```
totals = pd.crosstab(user_data['sex'], user_data['age'])
x = totals.columns.tolist()
y = totals.values.tolist()
```

`totals`:

```
age  19  20  21
sex            
F     1   4   3
M     3   4   5
```

`x`:

```
[19, 20, 21]
```

`y`:

```
[[1, 4, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```